# What is the advantages\disadvantages of applying the “allow clients to export cache tiles” in the ArcGIS server

Tags: arcgis-server, tilecache

I couldn’t figure out what is the advantages\disadvantages of applying the “allow clients to export cache tiles”in the ArcGIS server when setting advanced cache settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//015400000414000000) states (emphasis mine):

> The ArcGIS client APIs allow apps to download map tiles from the
>   server for offline use. When you check the checkbox Allow clients to
>   export cache tiles, you authorize these downloads to occur.
>
> **Large downloads of tiles can negatively affect your server performance
>   and overwhelm the client device.** Use the Limit export cache to setting
>   to define the maximum number of tiles a client can request at once.
>
> Exported tiles are placed in the server output directory. When you've
>   allowed clients to export tiles, you may want to increase the maximum
>   allowed age for files in the server output directory. **The default of
>   10 minutes may not be long enough for the client to retrieve the tiles
>   before they are cleaned up.** See Editing a server directory in Manager
>   for steps on how to make this edit.

Comment: Many thanks Vince, but I am still a little bit confused how this could help the end users, I have map services which is cached at different scales, does this means that when the user consumes the map service then the tiles will be stored in the output folder then what will happen next ? Are they transferred to the user’s machine? How will this help the end user/administrator? How about the performance in the server and the end user Machine. on the other hand what do I lose if this property wasn’t checked ?

Comment: I can't replace the documentation, which covers all these topics.